# Couchdb - date range + multiple query parameters

Tags: couchdb

I want to be able query the couchdb between dates, I know that this can be done with `startkey` and `endkey` (it works fine), but is it possible to do query for example like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE 
DateTime >= '2011-04-12T00:00:00.000' AND 
DateTime <= '2012-05-25T03:53:04.000'
AND 
  Status = 'Completed'
AND
Job_category = 'Installation'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally-speaking, establishing indexes on multiple fields grows in complexity as the number of fields increases.

My main question is: do `Status` and `Job_category` need to be queried dynamically too? If not, your view is simple:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.Status === 'Completed' && doc.Job_category === 'Installation') {
    emit(doc.DateTime); // this line may change depending on how you break up and emit the datetimes
  }
}
```

Views are *fairly* cheap, (depending on the size of your database) so don't be afraid to establish several that cover different cases. I would expect something like `Status` to have predefined list of available options, as oppposed to `Job_category` which seems like it *could* be more related to user input.

If you need those fields to be dynamic, you can just add them to the index as well:

```
function (doc) {
  emit([ doc.Status, doc.Job_category, doc.DateTime ]);
}
```

Then you can use an array as your `start_key`. For example:

```
start_key=["Completed", "Installation", ...]
```

tl;dr: use "static" views where you have a predetermined list of values for a given field. while possible to query "dynamic" views with multiple fields, the complexity grows very quickly.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thx a lot for you answer.